# How do I change the font size of a small section of my document without defining a new font family in XeTeX?

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontsize

I am writing a document where I am using many different font sizes in different areas of the document. It seems as though with XeTeX, you need to define a new font family just to change the font size of some text. I have to do this as follows every time I want a different font size:

```
\newfontfamily\someuniquename[<font features, like font size>]{<name of font, usually default font>}
```

This is the only way I find fonts with different sizes defined in the posts I searched. My question is: is there an easier, better, or more efficient way to change font size, preferably in pts, in XeTeX?

Unfortunately it seems like environments like `\Large` and `\LARGE` don't work with these fonts.

Comment: `\newfontfamily\myfont{Some Font}` and then `{\Large\myfont text}` will do.

Comment: The premise of your question is simply false. Can you show a minimal document that shows that `\Large` etc. don't work with fonts defined via `\newfontfamily`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the package [`anyfontsize`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/anyfontsize). This works with all engines (pdfTeX, XeTeX, LuaTeX).

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont Hello\\
    \fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont World\\
    \fontsize{200}{220}\selectfont!
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the question but whatever the problem I never saw a need to use anyfontsize, which is very old and patches kernel commands.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer if you want a big heading or sth, I guess you can use it. The OP accepted the answer, so I hope it solves the problem.

Comment: Your document gives the same output with xelatex and lualatex without the package. And with pdflatex you only need to load `\RequirePackage{fix-cm}` before `\begin{document}` (which doesn't do harm with the other engines).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes, it really works. I have found the similar solution, which was introduced to use with pdflatex. Didn't know it works without the package for other engines.

Answer (score 4):

I can see no issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\myfont}{Futura}

\begin{document}

{\large\myfont Text\par}

{\Huge\myfont Text\par}

{\small\myfont Text\par}

{\tiny\myfont Text\par}

{\fontsize{60}{75}\myfont Text}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's because I'm smart and I forgot the `\par`